# colocar uma coluna na tabela para marcar como vista

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho esta consulta e mostro numa tabela:

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<fieldset>
 <table cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
   <td>
 <strong>Insira data de inicio:</strong> <input type="Date" name="inicio" placeholder="PESQUISAR">
 </td>
</tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
 <table cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
   <td>
 <strong>Insira data de fim:</strong> <input type="Date" name="fim" placeholder="PESQUISAR">
 </td>
</tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>
 <input type="submit" name="pesquisa" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

```
<?php  

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

if(isset($_POST['inicio']) && isset($_POST['fim']))
{

    $inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
    $fim = $_POST['fim'];
    $result_cursos = "SELECT DataRegisto,
       Dia,
       TipoRefeicao,
       Refeicao,
       Hora,
       Motivo,
       Sugestao,
       Colaborador

FROM centrodb.RegistoDiario

WHERE DataRegisto >= '$inicio' AND DataRegisto <= '$fim'";
    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Data</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Dia</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tipo de Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Refeicao</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Hora da Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Motivo do incumprimento</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Sugestões/Observações</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Dia'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['TipoRefeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Refeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Hora'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Motivo'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Sugestao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;

?>
```

Quero acrescentar uma coluna a esta tabela para registar na base de dados como vista.

Como o exemplo que coloco esta imagem, ter uma coluna para marcar como vista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como assim 'como vista'? e em qual coluna na primeira ou na segunda? se na segunda tabela, em qual campo da query que retorna essa informação?

Comment: Vc tem uma imagem de como vc gostaria que ficasse? Sua pergunta está confusa...

Comment: Já coloquei, uma imagem como exemplo. é como marcar como concluída ao consultar a informação para sabermos que já vimos aquela informação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

if(isset($_POST['inicio']) && isset($_POST['fim']))
{

    $inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
    $fim = $_POST['fim'];
    $result_cursos = "SELECT DataRegisto,
       Dia,
       TipoRefeicao,
       Refeicao,
       Hora,
       Motivo,
       Sugestao,
       Colaborador

FROM centrodb.RegistoDiario

WHERE DataRegisto >= '$inicio' AND DataRegisto <= '$fim'";
    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Data</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Dia</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tipo de Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Refeicao</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Hora da Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Motivo do incumprimento</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Sugestões/Observações</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Vista</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Dia'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['TipoRefeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Refeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Hora'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Motivo'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Sugestao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type='checkbox' name= 'Vista'> </td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora só preciso que faça o `update` na tabela da base de dados